# Python: How to open json and html files in notepad?

Tags: python

Im trying to open json and html files in notepad. I have the following code:

```
def openFile():
    fileName = listbox_1.get(ACTIVE)
    if fileName.endswith("json") or fileName.endswith("htm"):
        os.system("notepad.exe" + fileName)
    elif fileName.endswith("jpeg"):
        os.startfile(fileName)
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(title="Error", message="File is not relevant, please choose one with a directory")
```

The problem is at the moment all that happens is that a command prompt window flashes up for about a second then disappears. I need for the content of the file to be displayed in notepad.

Using python 3.3 on windows

Thanks in advance

Comment: change os.system("notepad.exe" + fileName) to os.system("notepad.exe " + fileName)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed a space in `system` call. Proposed fix:

```
os.system('notepad.exe {}'.format(fileName))
```